# How can I manage windows of applications opened using Win32 API (Notepad, Word, Outlook, Chrome etc.)

Tags: go, winapi, hook, win32-process, setwindowlong

How can we manage the wndproc function of the applications we run using the Win32 api? The software language I use is Go.

I tried more than one method but couldn't do it. Can you help?

[I am learning the HANDLE (HWND) value of notepad application with Microsoft Spy ++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CXP5.png)

[Then I watch the changes on Notepad ++ over SPY ++.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SXMz.png)

Just like with Spy ++, please help me manage the custom WNPROC function I wrote.

```
func main() {

    hwnd := w32.HWND(3736818)
    go SetWindowLongTest(w32.HWND(hwnd))
    time.Sleep(99999 * time.Second)
}


func SetWindowLongTest(hwnd w32.HWND) {
    result, err := win.SetWindowLongPtr(win.HWND(hwnd), win.GWL_WNDPROC, syscall.NewCallback(MyNewWndProc))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("SetWindowLongPtr", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}



func MyNewWndProc(hwnd w32.HWND, uMsg uint, wParam w32.WPARAM, lParam w32.LPARAM) uintptr {
    fmt.Println(uMsg)
    fmt.Println("myNewWndProc", hwnd)
    return 0
}

  Result: 
    PS C:\Users\Cingozr\go\src> go run .\main.go
    SetWindowLongPtr Access is denied.
    0
```

Method 2:

```
func main() {

    hwnd := w32.HWND(3736818)
    go SetClassLongTest(w32.HWND(hwnd))
    time.Sleep(99999 * time.Second)
}

func SetClassLongTest(hwnd w32.HWND) {
    result, err := w32.SetClassLongPtrW(hwnd, -24, syscall.NewCallback(MyNewWndProc))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("SetClassLongPtrW Err", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("SetClassLongPtrW", result)

}

func MyNewWndProc(hwnd w32.HWND, uMsg uint, wParam w32.WPARAM, lParam w32.LPARAM) uintptr {
    fmt.Println(uMsg)
    fmt.Println("myNewWndProc", hwnd)
    return 0
}

Result:
PS C:\Users\Cingozr\go\src> go run .\main.go
SetClassLongPtrW Err Access is denied.
SetClassLongPtrW 0
```

Comment: You are roughly a decade away from understanding the system in enough detail to safely perform the changes you attempted to. Although it is very likely, that what you have asked for and the solution your problem aren't the same thing. The result is what's known as the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: How should I approach this situation? @iinspectable

Comment: `1` Learn a systems programming language. `2` Work through Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X). `3` Don't rush it; you'll need to *thoroughly* understand an API that's both old and huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you cannot replace the window procedure cross-process with [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) and
[`SetClassLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclasslongptrw) .

> Calling `SetWindowLongPtr` with the `GWLP_WNDPROC` index **creates a
> subclass of the window class** used to create the window. An
> application can subclass a system class, **but should not subclass a
> window class created by another process**.
>
> Calling `SetClassLongPtr` with the `GCLP_WNDPROC` index **creates a
> subclass of the window class** that affects all windows subsequently
> created with the class. An application can subclass a system class,
> **but should not subclass a window class created by another process**.

In addition, the hwnd parameter of SetWindowLongPtr also has UIPI restrictions:

> The **SetWindowLongPtr** function fails if the process that owns the
> window specified by the hWnd parameter is at a higher process
> privilege in the UIPI hierarchy than the process the calling thread
> resides in.
>
> **Windows XP/2000:**   The **SetWindowLongPtr** function fails if the window
> specified by the hWnd parameter does not belong to the same process as
> the calling thread.

It is recommended to use [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa), if you want to monitor window messages.
You could read this document: [Using Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-hooks)

You could also [create your own window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window), with the same `WNDCLASSEX`(GetClassLongPtr from the target window) and style(GetWindowLongPtr from the target window).

Or you've already known what you are doing, try dll injection.